# Embed watermark during video playback

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, azure-media-services

Is it possible to embed a watermark identifying the person who's viewing a video, so if he saves the file and share with someone else, his name will appear on it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  Without knowing your specific technologies, etc, the basic process is to edit the stream server side to add the water mark before sending the data to the client.  You'll probably have to edit each frame of the stream.

Comment: I currently don't have any tech stack defined. I'm a .Net developer, but I don't have any cloud platform or application defined. I was thinking on using a Web Seminar service, however they are expensive and usually don't protect the content.